# How to get first video frame?

Tags: objective-c, macos, video, media, vlc

I am programming media player using VLCKit. I want to take preview picture of the video. How can i do that using VLCKit or maybe another tools?

P.S. I've already used AVFoundation and QTKit, but it didn't work. They argue on video format (.mkv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use VLCKit's thumbnailer class. It is doing everything for you.